# in Twig how to compare if date is within X days?

Tags: php, date, symfony, twig

I'm using twig to flag a row in a table, if the date associated with that row is less than 30 days old.

Twig's documentation states that to compare two date objects, you have to convert the object to date first, and then make a comparison this way:

`{% if date(yourDate) < date(-'30days') %} ... {% endif %}`

However, it doesn't specify how to pass the date format for the left side of the comparison, I understand that Twig's date function is some sort of a wrapper for PHP's date.

In PHP I would usually call:

`$myDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $myDate);`

but in Twig apparently there's no way to specify the original date's format in order to convert it to another format, or at least it's not in the documentation.

This is what I've tried:

`{% if date(d.LastDate) > date('-30days') %}...{% endif %}`

`{% if d.LastDate | format("Y-m-d") > date('-30days') %}...{% endif %}`

`{% if date("m/d/Y", d.LastEmailSentDate) > date('-30days') %}...{% endif %}`

Those conditions and their variations return the following exception in Symfony2:

```
 An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (---)")
```

My controller is returning a date in the format: `m/d/Y` and I just want to flag that row if that date is less than 30 days old.

Comment: You can add a function called `getIsDateLessThan31DaysOld()` in your entity, and make it return true of false. Then call this function in Twig: `{% if d.isDateLessThan31DaysOld %}...{% endif %}`. It should be easier to write PHP code than Twig code.

Comment: This should not belong to templates. Provide your model[s] with a proper method.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Compare the two dates by getting the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (PHP Date Format `U`)

```
{% if d.LastDate|date("U") > "-30 days"|date("U") %}
    <p>Less than 30 days old</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 18):

`Twig 1.6` supports date comparison.

```
{% if date(d.LastDate) > date("-30 days") %}
    <p>Less than 30 days old</p>
{% endif %}

{% if date(d.LastDate) > date("now") %}
    <p>Future date</p>
{% endif %}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP 5.3 There is a way with more accuracy.

```
{# endDate and startDate are strings or DateTime objects #}
{% set difference = date(endDate).diff(date(startDate)) %}
{% set leftDays = difference.days %}
{% if leftDays > 30 %}
  Less than 30 days old
{% else %}
  More than 30 days old
{% endif %}
```

Explanation:

PHP 5.3 `DateTime` object has [`diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method which return a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object with the result difference between `endDate` and `beginDate`
Twig

Twig [`date`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html) function always return a `DateTime` object so we can call `diff` method

Finally we can access to the properties of the `DateInterval` object or format it with the Twig date filter.

Note: There is no need of wrap endDate or startDate with the date function if the variable is already a DateTime object.

Note2: `DateTime` is used here as synonym of `DateTimeInterface`.